# Using Brightcover player with external JS

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, brightcove

I'm having a heck of a time getting the brightcove Smart Player API to work on any external JS files. I have no problems with calling the standard API methods like `onTemplateLoad` and `onTemplateReady` within the `index.html`, but as soon as they are moved out to external coffeescript, i get nothing :( All the API documentation from BrightCove uses internal javascript.

The `BrightCoveExperiences.js` is included in the HTML body, right next to the player `div`.

My JS load order is thus (in Jade), whereby `beast.js` is the goods:

```
script(type="text/javascript", src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="js/contentful.min.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="js/handlebars.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="js/showdown.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="js/moment.js")
script(src="js/beast.js", type="text/javascript")
```

Within `beast.js`, I'm injecting the following:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?&amp;width=480&amp;height=270&amp;flashID=myExperience&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;playerID=1507808033001&amp;playerKey=AQ~~%2CAAABXxBZKsE~%2CAdU2xXeQoKCatdLR1Pb_eo4UzCFcjSKc&amp;isVid=true&amp;isUI=true&amp;dynamicStreaming=true&amp;%40videoPlayer=2114345471001&amp;includeAPI=true&amp;templateLoadHandler=onTemplateLoad&amp;templateReadyHandler=brightcove%5B%22templateReadyHandlermyExperience%22%5D&amp;autoStart=&amp;debuggerID=&amp;originalTemplateReadyHandler=onTemplateReady&amp;startTime=1408987173053" id="myExperience" width="480" height="270" class="BrightcoveExperience" seamlesstabbing="undefined">

<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
<param name="seamlessTabbing" value="false">
<param name="swliveconnect" value="true">
<param name="wmode" value="window"><param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF">
```

Which, in theory, should call the `onTemplateReady` and `onTemplateLoad` functions:

```
onTemplateLoad = (experienceID) ->
    player = brightcove.api.getExperience(experienceID)
    APIModules = brightcove.api.modules.APIModules
    console.log 'im so loaded man'

onTemplateReady = (evt) ->
    videoPlayer = player.getModule(APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER)
    videoPlayer.play()
    console.log 'ready'
```

But alas... I should also mention, I'm not a BrightCove fan.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoffeeScript wraps the compiled JavaScript in a [self-invoking function](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope) to avoid polluting the global namespace:

> Although suppressed within this documentation for clarity, all CoffeeScript output is wrapped in an anonymous function:  `(function(){ ... })();` This safety wrapper, combined with the automatic generation of the `var` keyword, make it exceedingly difficult to pollute the global namespace by accident.

That means that your two functions

```
onTemplateLoad = (experienceID) -> ...
onTemplateReady = (evt) -> ...
```

are not globally available, they're hidden like this:

```
(function() {
    var onTemplateLoad = function(experienceId) { ... };
    var onTemplateReady = function(evt) { ... };
})();
```

You need to manually put them in the global scope:

```
window.onTemplateLoad = (experienceID) -> ...
window.onTemplateReady = (evt) -> ...
```

or, if you're sure they're at the top level within their `.coffee` file:

```
@onTemplateLoad = (experienceID) -> ...
@onTemplateReady = (evt) -> ...
```